# Call Function print a-z. lowercase to uppercase

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes a lowercase letter and returns an uppercase one.
I also have a function that takes an uppercase letter and returns a lowercase one.

I would like to call the function that does this conversion to print the alphabet in either all capitals or all lowercase after it has converted my first letter you choose.

e.g. Function turns 'a' into 'A'
After doing this:
Now print A-Z in capital letters.

Answer Requirements.

https://justpaste.it/7f95f

Code Provided Below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char ToUpperCase(char _cInput);
char ToLowerCase(char _cInput);
char Letter;
int Menu;

int main() {
  cout << "This program changes any letter from lowercase to uppercase, it "
          "leaves uppercase letters as they already are."
       << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Menu: " << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "1) Convert a lowercase letter to uppercase." << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "2) Convert an uppercase letter to a lowercase one." << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "3) Quit." << endl;
  cout << endl;

  cin >> Menu;

  while (Menu > 3 || cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Use only the options avaliable." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin.clear();  // clear input buffer to restore cin to a usable state
    cin.ignore(); // ignore last input
    cin >> Menu;
  }

  if (Menu == 1) {
    cout << "Taking you to the Lowercase to Uppercase converter." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input a lowercase letter." << endl;
    cin >> Letter;

    while (isdigit(Letter)) {
      cout << Letter << ": Is not an acceptable input. Try again." << endl;
      cin >> Letter;
    }

    cout << ToUpperCase(Letter) << endl;
  } else if (Menu == 2) {
    cout << "Taking you to the Uppercase to Lowercase converter." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input an uppercase letter." << endl;
    cin >> Letter;

    while (isdigit(Letter)) {
      cout << Letter << ": Is not an acceptable input. Try again." << endl;
      cin >> Letter;
    }

    cout << ToLowerCase(Letter) << endl;
  } else if (Menu == 3) {
    cout << "Quitting Now." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return (0);
  }

  int iTemp;
  cin >> iTemp;
}

char ToUpperCase(char _cInput) {
  if (Letter >= 'A' && Letter <= 'Z') {
    cout << "This is already an Uppercase letter." << endl;
    cout << endl;
  } else if (Letter >= 'a' && Letter <= 'z') {
    _cInput = Letter - 32;

    cout << "This is a Lowercase letter." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The Uppercase version of this letter is: ";
  }

  return (_cInput);
}

char ToLowerCase(char _cInput) {
  if (Letter >= 'A' && Letter <= 'Z') {
    cout << "This is an Uppercase letter." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    _cInput = Letter + 32;

    cout << "The Lowercase version of this letter is: ";
  } else if (Letter >= 'a' && Letter <= 'z') {
    cout << "This is already a Lowercase letter." << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }
  return (_cInput);
}
```

https://pastecode.xyz/view/1a18904b

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Have you attempted this conversion at all? Seems like all you'd need to do is run a loop.

Comment: How do I print a-z by calling the function "ToUpperCase"

Comment: Why not use `std::toupper()` and `std::tolower()`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will find help here provided you respect some rules - what this question does not. As a new user, you really should read [ask]. Specifically, you are supposed to ask a precise and detailed question, showing you current code to make clear what precise pard you need help with. And you as supposed to show *in the question itself* enough code to allow others to reproduce what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::transform` to run a loop applying your function to all elements of the array.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

char ToUpperCase(char _cInput)
{ 
    if (_cInput >= 'a' && _cInput <= 'z')
    {
        _cInput -= 32;
    }

    return _cInput;
}

char ToLowerCase(char _cInput) 
{
  if (_cInput >= 'A' && _cInput <= 'Z') {
    _cInput += 32;
  }

  return _cInput;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 26> alphabet;

    std::generate(begin(alphabet),
                  end(alphabet), 
                  [n = 0] () mutable { return (n++) + 97; });

    std::cout << "original: \n";
    for(char c: alphabet) 
        std::cout << c << '\n';

    /*
     *  convert to upper case
     */
    std::array<char, 26> all_upper;

    std::transform(begin(alphabet), 
                   end(alphabet), 
                   begin(all_upper), 
                   ToUpperCase);

    std::cout << "all upper: \n";
    for(char c: all_upper) 
        std::cout << c << '\n';

    /*
     *  convert to lower case
     */
    std::array<char, 26> all_lower;

    std::transform(begin(all_upper), 
                   end(all_upper), 
                   begin(all_lower), 
                   ToLowerCase);

    std::cout << "all lower: \n";
    for(char c: all_lower) 
        std::cout << c << '\n';

    // check it didnt modify original
    // for(char c: alphabet) 
    //     std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! <3 This is what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

**How do I print a-z in capital letters by calling the "ToUpperCase" function?**
As per your question, you want to print the string, bellow could be one way to print.

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void toUpperCase(string &str) 
{ 
    int ln = str.length(); 
    for (int i=0; i<ln; i++) 
    { 
        if (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') 
        {
            str[i] = str[i] - 32; 
        }
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    string str = ""; 
    cout<< "Enter the string ";
    cin >> str;

    toUpperCase(str); 

    cout << str; 
    return 0; 
}
```

If you want to upper to lower then just

```
if(str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') 
str[i] = str[i] + 32;
```

Comment: I've edited my post, I think there was a misunderstanding. :)